# Date in(dd/mm/yyyy) format in XSLT file

Tags: xslt

How to display date in(dd/mm/yyyy) format in XSLt file.Could you please help me.

I tried and its displaying as 2018-04-13Z

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:ex="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" extension-element-prefixes="ex">
<xsl:value-of select="ex:date-time()"/>
```

This above code prints as (YYYY,MM,DD) i want in (dd/mm/yyyy) format .

Comment: Could you please edit your question to show the XSLT you have tried, along with a sample of your input XML. Thank you!

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:ex="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" extension-element-prefixes="ex">
<xsl:value-of select="ex:date()"/>   i tried this

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the XSLT please, as code is hard to read in comments. Also, can you include a sample of your input XML with the date in. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this answer is use full.
2.0

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-date(., '[M01]/[D01]/[Y0001]')"/>
```

1.0

```
<xsl:function name="ex:date-time">
    <xsl:param name="date"/>
    <xsl:variable name="yy" select="substring-before($date,'-')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="mm" select="substring-before(substring-after($date,'-'),'-')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="dd" select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after($date,'-'),'-'),'Z')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($dd,'/',$mm,'/',$yy)"/>
</xsl:function>
```

thanks,
Uday

Comment: I tried using the same above code but its showing me Could not compile stylesheet . So i tried with this code<xsl:value-of select="ex:date('[DD]/[MM]/[YYYY]')"/> i wrote in this format but its not showing me the current date.

Comment: @Uday `format-date()` function is a feature of `XSLT 2.0` version. Since the question contains a reference to `exslt` extensions, `XSLT 1.0` version is being used. Please provide the version in the answer so it will be helpful.

Comment: XSLT 1.0 version

Comment: Note that `xsl:function` is only available in XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT 1.0 does not have inbuilt functions to format dates. The extensions provided by http://exslt.org/date/index.html also mention that `format-date()` function is not stable.

In this case, you can use the `substring()` function to get the `DD`, `MM` and `YYYY` parts from the date returned by `ex:date-time()` and then using the `concat()` function, concatenate them with `/` separator.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="currDt" select="ex:date-time()" />
    <currDate><xsl:value-of select="$currDt" /></currDate>
    <formattedDate>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($currDt, 9, 2), '/', substring($currDt, 6, 2), '/', substring($currDt, 1, 4))" />
    </formattedDate>
</xsl:template>
```

Output

```
<currDate>2018-04-13T14:39:14+05:1800000</currDate>
<formattedDate>13/04/2018</formattedDate>
```

Comment: <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:variable name="currDt" select="ex:date-time()" />
   <currDate><xsl:value-of select="$currDt" /></currDate>
   <formattedDate>
   <fo:block>
   <fo:inline color="#FFFFFF" margin="90px" font-size="20pt">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($currDt, 9, 2), '/', substring($currDt, 6, 2), '/', substring($currDt, 1, 4))" />
   </fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
   </formattedDate>
      </xsl:template>  No error but it not showing me date

Comment: So what changes i need to do.?Could you please run this above code and let me know ..Actually i am printing this in a pdf